# ¿Qué quiere decir en inglés la frase "Mientras luche aquí buscando yo su luz,", especialmente el verbo "luche"?

Tags: verbos

Por favor, analice el verbo por lo menos.

He encontrado la frase en el himno "Todas las promesas" por R. Kelso Carter.

En inglés se titula "Standing on the Promises".

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a site about English language but ...

> *Mientras luche aquí buscando yo Su luz
>
>   siempre en Sus promesas confiaré.*

This can be translated to English approximately as:

> While I fight here searching for His light,
>   always in His promises I will trust.

Notice that the verb **fight** [*luchar*] is not present in the [original text](https://spanishworship.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/todas-las-promesas-del-senor-jesus/) by R. K. Carter. The Spanish hymn is not a translation, probably it only keeps the music and the main theme about promises.

***Luche*** is the first singular person of the **present subjunctive** of the verb *luchar*: *yo luche* (I fight). The subjunctive in Spanish is used to express more or less the same that the English form, *these include statements about one's state of mind, such as opinion, belief, purpose, intention, or desire.* [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

In Spanish, this:

> *mientras (yo) luche*

is a *complemento circunstancial de tiempo*. I think that the English equivalent is an *adverb clause of time*. It indicates **when** the action of the main verb occurs. In this case *when two things happen **at the same time**, we can use the word **while**, which mean 'during that time'* [source](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/adverb-time-clauses)

We can reorder the sentence a bit:

> I will always trust His promises while I fight here searching for His light.

The main verb is **trust**. I guess that the speaker is saying that he'll be all his life fighting, searching for the enlightment of God and that he will always trust His promises during the aforementioned life.
The speaker is expressing *belief, purpose, intention, or desire*.

Comment: Gracias por su buena respuesta!  Esa me ayudara cuando tengo que tocar mi guitarra y cantar este Domingo para mi iglesia!